# How to delete specific columns of a particular row from SQLite in Android

Tags: android

I need to write a query to delete specific columns of a particular row from SQLite in Android. I want to use it in the form of "db.delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)".

My application contains 4 columns for each row.  I need to delete only 2 columns of a particular row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete only columns of particular row. You have to delete either two columns for all rows or you have to set some definite value like null or 0 for that.

Answer (score 1):

db.delete is a convenience method for deleting rows in the database. This will delete the entire row not just a few columns in the row.

You cannot delete a particular column for a specific row. You can only delete column for the entire table.

So you may consider setting the column values of the particular with some default value like NULL or 0.